# Definition, Origin, and Extent of "Matter" as a title in Literature

Tags: etymology, literature

Why was "Matter" chosen for the [Matter of Britain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_of_Britain), the [Matter of France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_of_France) and the [Matter of Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_of_Rome)?

What would the exact definition of *"Matter"* be in this instance? Written/Printed Material, or a Theme/Group of Themes, or [*(obsolete) the essence; the pith; the embodiment*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/matter)? Whereas it seems to refer to [topics](http://faculty.goucher.edu/eng240/three_matters_of_romance.htm), we often hear it used as a proper noun to describe the Literature itself, such as *"in the Matter of Britain we often read of..."* So what did it mean in its original context and what has it come to mean - exactly - in the English language?

Who coined this term and when? Was it the old French poet [Jean Bodel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Bodel) (c. 1165 – c. 1210) who classified *"The Three Matters"* *["N'en sont que trois materes a nul home entendant / De France, et de Bretaigne, et de Rome la grant."]*, or was the term commonly used in regards to bodies of literature before him? And when if ever did it's use fall out of vogue?

Comment: And we have another question: did *matière* mean the same thing in French when Jean Bodel used it as *matter* does in English today? I think the answer to this question is *no*. From the OED: "The subject of a book, speech, etc.; a theme, a topic, a subject of exposition. In early use also: a narrative, an account, a tale. *Obsolete.*" One of their citations is (ca. 1340) *The matere of this boke is crist & his spouse.*

Comment: If a child is crying and his mother asks "What is the matter?", what does "matter" mean?

Comment: @Johan88 - I thought the question was on the meaning of "matter".

Comment: A progression from 'The Matter of Elbonia' to 'Thoughts / A Treatise on the Subject of Elbonia'  to 'Thoughts Concerning Elbonia' to  'On the Subject of / Concerning Elbonia'  to 'Elbonia' has probably occurred.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth q-_-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrases "the Matter of Britain," "the Matter of France," and the "Matter of Rome" seem to have been taken directly into English from Jean Bodel's verse some time in the late 19th century. Before then, "the Matter of Britian" seems to have been called by other names, such as ["the Arthurian Cycle,"](https://books.google.com/books?id=yE07AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA5&dq=%22arthurian+cycle%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjao9jr9NniAhVpdt8KHZt-A34Q6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22arthurian%20cycle%22&f=false) in English.

The first time I can find *"Matter of Britain"* used in Google books is in [The Flourishing of Romance and the Rise of Allegory](https://books.google.com/books?id=ReRSAAAAYAAJ&pg=PR2&dq=%22the+flourishing+of+romance+and+the+rise+of+allegory&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjm8Ijt7dniAhUMwlkKHeb2DVkQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=matter%20of%20britain&f=false) by George Saintbury, which was first published in 1897.

More evidence that these phrases were taken directly from Jean Bodel's verse into late 19th century English, and were not timeworn English phrases, comes from the 1920 book *A History of English Literature*, by William Allan Neilson, in which we find

> The great majority of the romances fall into groups or cycles concerned with what an old French poet called the “matter of Britain,” the “matter of France,” and the "matter of Rome."

Since the word comes to us from Old French, and seems to have been translated into English using the cognate word *matter* (whether or not this was the best English word), what we really need is a good Old French dictionary.

The [Anglo-Norman Dictionary](http://www.anglo-norman.net/) has for one of the definitions of *matire*:

> subject matter, topic (of a literary work),

which is exactly the sense that Jean Bodel used it in. (And *matire* is the same word as Jean Bodel's *matere* – Old French spelling was as variable as Middle English spelling.)

The OED has the very similar definition (which is not surprising, since a large amount of Old French vocabulary was incorporated into Middle English after the Norman Conquest):

> "The subject of a book, speech, etc.; a theme, a topic, a subject of exposition. In early use also: a narrative, an account, a tale. Obsolete."

One of their citations for this meaning is (ca. 1340)

> *The matere of this boke is crist & his spouse.*

Comment: Nitpick: _matter_ is not really cognate to OF _matere_ – it is a descendent of it, having been borrowed from OF into English. Cognates are generally defined as inherited words which share a common ancestor.

Comment: Wikipedia: "The Matter of Britain **is the body of Medieval literature**.." "The Matter of France, also known as the Carolingian cycle, **is a body of literature**.." "..the Matter of Rome **was the literary cycle..**" It does not say "The Matter of Britain/France/Rome **is the subject matter/topic(s) of** the body of literature.." That is how "Matter" is used, as a proper noun referring to the literature itself, not the subject of the literature. And it leaves me wondering if we can title modern bodies of work (literature or otherwise) "The Matter of so-and-so"

Comment: @Johan88: the definition from the *Anglo-Norman Dictionary* is the meaning that Jean Bodel intended.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks, yes. That addresses the Origin of the term, but how about the 'Extent' of Matter? It seems Jean Bodel used *matere* meaning *"subject/topic"* but, translated to English, "Matter" aquired the OED obsolete meaning of *"In early use also: a narrative, an account, a tale"*, which then fell into obsoletion, hence the question of it's *extent*. Was the said obsolete meaning (of a narrative/tale **as opposed to** a subject/topic) limited to only these three bodies of literature (or four if you include the Matter of Troy - part of the Matter of Rome)?

Comment: @PeterShor Or was this obsolete meaning used in regards to other narratives/tales?

Comment: @PeterShor And when did this meaning of a narrative/tale fall into obsoletion?

Comment: No, "matter" acquired the meaning you're asking about in the 19th or 20th century; it's not in the OED.

Comment: @PeterShor q0.0p whaaat? Your first comment on the original question says "From the OED: "... In early use also: a narrative, an account, a tale. *Obsolete*."" And that definition is quoted in your answer. Now I'm confused???

Comment: I misunderstood your comment. The last citation in the OED that clearly means "narrative/tale" seems to be 1340 "Ich nelle non more zigge, ac hier ich wille endi mine matire." But there are a few more citations that might have this sense up to around the mid-16th century.

Comment: The obsolete meaning of *narrative/tale* was not restricted to "the matter of Britain", and "the matter of Britain" seems to only have become an English phrase in the late 19th century.

Comment: @PeterShor That's very interesting, and surprising, since Jean Bodel died c.1165-1210. Maybe you could incorporate all this comment info into your answer so we can delete these many comments

Answer (score 2):

It's a straight borrowing from the Latin [*Res*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/res) ["matter, thing,"](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/res) which we still use daily in the form of *Re:* "in the matter of:"; Latin books were often titled beginning *De Re ....* (Concerning the matter/nature of....), e.g. Agricola's *De Re Metallica* (On the Nature of Metals), Cicero's *De Re Publica* (On the Republic, which is literally the 'public matter') -- as distinct from the usage of genitive *rerum* as actual "things" in Lucretius's [*De Rerum Natura*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rerum_Natura) (On the Nature of Things).

Cf. [Arthurus (rex)](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthurus_(rex)): "Saeculis XI, XII, XIII multae mythistoriae de vita Arthuri scriptae sunt in Cambria, Francia, Anglia; id genus fabularum poetae Francici *Matière de Bretagne* appellabant, scilicet '**Res Britanniae**'. "